# Can pCloud be used to sync files between two computers?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I've been investigating if [pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com) is a possible replacement for Dropbox, but I must say, I'm confused.

Dropbox is very good at keeping files in sync on two or more computers, and having those files available *locally* on both computers.

However, after installing pCloud it's not clear if this is easy or even possible with pCloud. I can see that it is possible to access files through the browser-based interface, but is it possible to have the same folder available and editable locally on two different computers, and have changes automatically synchronized between computers?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced Dropbox with pCloud a while ago, mainly because I was fed up with Dropbox constantly harassing me to upgrade and generally speaking being obnoxious about a number of little things.

pCloud has ONE downside for me, and then, maybe I didn't set it up right: The pCould client has to be running for you to be able to access your files offline.

In other words, if, like me, you've got it installed on two different OSes on the same PC, you must fire them both up (not a the same time, of course) to sync your pCloud folders on both.

But that's about it. pCloud suits my needs, is very fast, doesn't create duplicates and triplicates the way Dropbox does sometimes, so I like it.

And yes, if you've got it running on two or more PCs on your home LAN, they'll sync over LAN instantly, the way Dropbox does.

That should be enough for you to at least try it.

That and the fact that pCloud's free tier is much more generous than Dropbox's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pCloud to sync files in between several computers by using **pCloud Drive**.

With pCloud Drive installed, you will access your pCloud files via a "virtual drive". You can browse your pCloud-hosted files in your file manager, but they are stored in the cloud. Default behaviour is that the files are downloaded to your device when you request them, like opening a file, or if you select them to be "available offline".

Inside pCloud Drive there is an option called **(pCloud) Sync**. Here you can set up folder pairs that are synchronised. Using Sync, the files are kept locally on the machine, and also synchronised with the pCloud server. When you change a file, the changed file will be synchronised.

You can install pCloud Drive on multiple computers, and set up Sync using the same folder pair(s). This way you can have the same files synchronised across multiple devices.

From [pCloud's FAQ](https://www.pcloud.com/help/drive-help-center/whats-the-difference-between-pcloud-drive-and-pcloud-sync):

> **pCloud Drive** is a desktop app, which makes it possible to work with
> your files as if they are on your computer, but without taking space
> from your HDD. It works as a virtual drive, which can extend the
> available space on your device with up to 2 TB. Once your files are in
> pCloud Drive, you will easily be able to access, edit and share with
> others.
>
> **(pCloud) Sync** is a feature in pCloud Drive. It allows you to connect
> locally-stored folders from your PC with pCloud Drive. This connection
> goes both ways, so if you edit or delete the files you’re syncing from
> your computer, this means that you'll also be editing them or deleting
> them from pCloud Drive.